# IIS cannot access page through domain

Tags: asp.net, iis, port

I have successfully published a website(whatever.com) and it is accessible for global users except for the server itself.

If I input the domain(whatever.com) in the server's browser, it would display **"This page can't be displayed."**

How could I fix it that could let me access the page through the server's browser?

Other information:

1. Users from other computers could access my page.
2. Localhost(http://localhost/) works in the server's browser but domain(http://whatever.com/) doesn't.
3. Port 80 is opened.

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html Edit your question to include the report, so that others can know if you really configured it the right way.

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the domain "whatever.com" is in the bindings list on the website from IIS.

You might have a DNS problem on the server, you can manually map the "whaterver.com" domain in the hosts (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) file of your server by appending the following line:

```
127.0.0.1     whatever.com
```